# How can I compare a class against an enum and have Intellisense suggest the enums?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

At first, I had defined a class like so:

```
Public Class Company
      Public CompanyName As String
      (... some other properties ...)
End Public
```

In my code, I often have to check against the company.

I used this:

```
If SomeCompany.CompanyName = "Google" Then
```

Since this is time taking and error prone, I have introduced a new property:

```
Public Enum eWellKnownCompany
     eNone = 0
     eAmazon = 1
     eGoogle = 2
End Enum

Public Class Company
      Public Identifier As eWellknownCompany
      Public CompanyName As String
      (... some other properties ...)
End Public
```

Now I use this:

```
If SomeCompany.Identifier = eGoogle Then
```

This way I can avoid making spelling errors.
However, coding like this still takes too much time for me.

Ideally, I would like to be able to make the If Then statement like this:

```
If SomeCompany = eGoogle Then
```

I know that this is checking an object against an enum and therefore not working.

Is there perhaps a smart solution similar to this in VB.NET anyways?

Per suggestion by @John, I have added operator overrides.
This works fine, but it does not work as I had expected.

I expected Intellisense to suggest the Enums only.
(I hope my post makes more sense now and shows how I expect it to work.)

Instead, I see this:

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You could overload the equality operator for that class but, seriously, if it takes too much time to qualify a property but you're using that silly version of Hungarian notation then your priorities are screwed up.

Comment: @John Hmmm, I am doing it to my liking. Had I found the Hungarian notation to be not important, I would have dropped it already. And sometimes I do NOT use Hungarian notation. I only use it when I need it.

Comment: Oh man, for you I am changing the post and drop the "cls" LOL

Comment: How do you manage to use all those classes from .NET itself without their having a "cls" prefix? Same goes for enums without an "e" prefix? No one has problems with those so you never need to use such prefixes yourself. You can do what you want, of course, but if you want to prefix type and field names like that then you're being silly. With modern code editors and no need for short, cryptic variable names, even proper Hungarian Notation is obsolete and what you're doing has never been a good thing.

Comment: I'd think you would need to be making that check a LOT for speed to matter.  Intellisense will usually speed it up quite a bit, after I've done something like that once or twice it will usually be the default pick when I type the dot.  Remember, too, that it's usually more important for code to be clearly written than for it to be concise to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this code:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim sc1 As New SomeClass With {.SomeProperty = SomeEnum.SomeField}

        Console.WriteLine(sc1 = SomeEnum.SomeField)
        Console.WriteLine(sc1 = SomeEnum.SomeOtherField)
        Console.WriteLine(sc1 <> SomeEnum.SomeField)
        Console.WriteLine(sc1 <> SomeEnum.SomeOtherField)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Enum SomeEnum
    SomeField
    SomeOtherField
End Enum

Public Class SomeClass

    Public Property SomeProperty As SomeEnum

    Public Shared Operator =(someClass As SomeClass, someEnum As SomeEnum)
        Return someClass.SomeProperty = someEnum
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <>(someClass As SomeClass, someEnum As SomeEnum)
        Return someClass.SomeProperty <> someEnum
    End Operator

End Class
```

and the output was this:

```
True
False
False
True
```

That basically allows you to do as you want, although you obviously still need to qualify the enum field with the enum name, which you omitted from your question.

EDIT:

If you're really determined to be able to use the fields of the enumeration unqualified then this will work:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim sc1 As New SomeClass With {.SomeProperty = SomeEnum.SomeField}

        Console.WriteLine(sc1 = SomeField)
        Console.WriteLine(sc1 = SomeOtherField)
        Console.WriteLine(sc1 <> SomeField)
        Console.WriteLine(sc1 <> SomeOtherField)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Enum SomeEnum
    SomeField
    SomeOtherField
End Enum

Public Class SomeClass

    Public Property SomeProperty As SomeEnum

    Public Shared Operator =(someClass As SomeClass, someEnum As SomeEnum)
        Return someClass.SomeProperty = someEnum
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <>(someClass As SomeClass, someEnum As SomeEnum)
        Return someClass.SomeProperty <> someEnum
    End Operator

End Class

Public Module Module2

    Public Const SomeField As SomeEnum = SomeEnum.SomeField
    Public Const SomeOtherField As SomeEnum = SomeEnum.SomeOtherField

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you. Where do you define the enums? If I add them to a public module, it won't accept using a not fully qualified name. If I add it to the class, it says: Can't expose type xxxx outside the project through class Company.

Comment: @tmighty, an enumeration is a first-class type, just like a class, module or structure. Unless you have a very good reason, you don't declare them inside another type. Classes, modules and structures are and should be generally declared in their own code file, named after the type. You can do the same thing for enumerations but, given that they are usually small and simple, I tend to create one code file named Enumerations.vb and declare all my enumerations in there.

Comment: If I declare the enum in a public module as you suggested, and I use the following in my "Company" class:     "Public Property Identifier As eCompany", the compiler tells me "cannot expose type 'Enumerations.eCompany' outside the project through class 'Company'".

Comment: *"If I declare the enum in a public module as you suggested"*. Where exactly did I suggest that? I specifically said to NOT do that and my code example doesn't show it being done. I told you to declare enumerations in their own code file, not inside another type, module or otherwise. There's no point my typing words if you're not reading them.

Comment: I wasn't aware that enums can be declared without any module or class. I have now put them in a "blank" file. Now the compiler error is gone, but I still can't compare it as I intended to: "If someCompany = Amazon" throws the compiler error "Amazon is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level".

Comment: The only way you can refer to a member of a type without qualifying it with either the type or an instance of the type is if it's a declared in a module. You could declare constants in a module of your enumerated type with the same names and values as its fields and then you could write code the way you want. Why you would want to do that is beyond me but writing silly code is your prerogative. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you. I found myself wanting to write code the way I explained in my post, and I wondered if that is possible. You can test something against Nothing, and I just wanted a quick way to do that with something else. I think my wish is reasonable.

Comment: My choices are either "if someCompany.Identifier = eCompany.Google then" or "if someCompany = Google then". The first version is just too long, too much to read and too much to write. If you have any other solution, please tell me about it.